# How to convert MS word document with chart in it to PDF without office.word.interop c#

Tags: c#, pdf, doc

We want to convert word docx file to PDF automatically and without using MS office word installed. The problem is there are a few charts in the doc file. These charts did not being converted.

Is there anyone know how to auto convert doc file with chart to PDF. prefer C#.

Thanks

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41492686/6758312). I suggested a number of libraries that could help with this, including [the professional LEADTOOLS SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-converter). The SDK has a free evaluation you can try. (Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of this toolkit)

Answer (score -1):

At the risk of sounding like an advertisement, on a previous client of mine we used Aspose (http://www.aspose.com).  It is a pay library to convert documents to PDF.  Not fully sure how it would work with charts, but worth a shot. If not there are other libraries out there that I'm sure do this already.

I would have left this as a comment, but I'm not level 50 yet :-(

Comment: Thanks Rob! I tried but the chart in the doc file did not being converted.